# An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested class: Sistema [No AutoLoad] CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

So, I was following a tutorial and modifying the code, and there is a point that I can't fix it, a can't see why CI isn't loading the class.
This is the function:

```
function set_theme($propriedade, $valor, $replace = TRUE){
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('sistema');
    if($replace){
        $ci->sistema->theme[$propriedade] = $valor;
    }else{
        if (!isset($ci->sistema->theme[$propriedade])) {
            $ci->sistema->theme[$propriedade] = "";
        }
    $ci->sistema->theme[$propriedade] .= $valor;
   }
} // <-- end set_theme -->
```

And the class **sistema.php** is:

```
<?php

class MY_Sistema{
    protected $ci;
    public $theme = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->helper('functions');
    }
}
```

And when I call `set_theme()` it on the controller, it just give the error:

```
An Error Was Encountered  Unable to load the requested class: Sistema
```

Someone got an Idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your library to Sistema and place it into the application/libraries folder

```
class Sistema
{
    protected $ci;
    public $theme = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->helper('functions');
    }
}
```

You can find the documentation for Loading a library [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html?highlight=librar#CI_Loader::library)

Comment: Thanks, now that you said (I looked the doc before) but I didn't realized one thing that I was forgetting : the tutorial that I was following use CI 2x and I'm using the 3x but thanks, I already rename the file sistema.php to Sistema.php (just in case).